# Passing string argument from bash script to python3

Tags: python, bash, python-3.8

I am trying to read multiple directory locations from a text file using a bash script and pass as argument to another python script. The directory name contains space which shows

```
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 1B/PHASE/PHASE_90
```

I am using following bash script:

```
filename='filter_directory.txt'
line_counter=1
while read line; do
# reading each line
    echo "Processing Directorie: $line_counter : $line"
    python3 test.py -i $line
    line_counter=$((line_counter+1))
    echo "Finish Directorie: $line_counter!!!"
    done < $filename
```

`test.py` is:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--input", "-i", type=str, default='./input', help='Calculation LUMA image folder')
arg = parser.parse_args()
input_path = arg.input
print(input_path)
```

`filter_directory.txt` contains:

```
version_of_study/Study 1B/PHASE/PHASE_90
version_of_study/Study 1B/PHASE/PHASE_91
version_of_study/Study 1B/PHASE/PHASE_92
version_of_study/Study 1B/PHASE/PHASE_93
```

Could you help me to import the directory name from text file to python by bash script?

Answer (score 1):

You should just [quote](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) `$line` like `python3 test.py -i "$line"` to group the argument. You can use tools like [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to identify issues like these in shell scripts. [This article](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html) is a great introduction to the different ways to correct use/avoid variable expansion and word splitting.

Comment: +1 for the shellcheck link. Genuinely needed a link to some form of shell debugging tool!! I find bug fixing bash like pulling teeth sometimes!!! I tend to resort to lots of echo statements and things like that!